# Where to put the booster pump at customer substation in a district heating system?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, pumps, hydraulics, heating-systems

In a district heating system, one of the houses in the distribution net is not getting the desired heat into their house. This is because the pipes of this customer which connects them to the distribution system, are smaller than required; which leads to sudden pressure drop.

The solutions I can see are either to replace this customer`s supply pipe with the bigger one, or setting up a booster pump system at the customer. If I were to decide on putting a pump system, where should I put the pump; on the customer supply pipe or return pipe?

[image]

Comment: Is your pump better at depression or pressure?

Comment: You need to check what the pump is capable of, some can push well but not "draw or suck" others suck better than push... If you are working on this type of system then you should know how pumps work....

Comment: now i understand, so it comes to the type of the system.

Comment: @Solar Mike If only boils down to the pump system, then say I put the pump on the return line; in this case shouldn`t pump also overcome the pressure drop in the customer heat exchangers? In that case putting on the supply line makes more sense, is this right?

Comment: What are the pump characteristics? Any idea of the flow rate you need to achieve for max heating load? From that and the size of the pipes you can work out what you need.

Comment: Max flow rate will be around 1 m3/s. I now have the required the pressure drop calculations, so I am accordingly trying to select the pump.

Comment: a flow rate of 1m^3/s, so what pump are you looking at?

Comment: 1m3/hour =) yep. sorry.